# JAAS isn't working in Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, jaas, websphere-8

I have defined my login module under `Global Security->JAAS -> Application Login`.
But how would my server and deployed application will know about it.
Plus When I tried to check **Golobal Security->Enable administrative security**, I got an error saying:

```
Validation failed: SECJ7724E: Error in the user registry configuration unable to verify access to the user registry.
You must supply the primary administrative user name on the active registry or realm panels to enable security.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application becomes aware of the WAS-defined security roles via ibm-application-bnd.xml.

Here's an example that binds roles matching a Custom JDBC Registry (the CLIENT role) and LDAP/AD (the other roles) defined within WAS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                     http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd" 
                 version="1.0">
     <security-role name="CLIENT">
        <group name="Clients" />
     </security-role>
     <security-role name="STAFF">
        <group name="Contractors" access-id="CN=Contractors,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,o=StaffLDAP"/>
        <group name="ContractorsNoVPN" access-id="CN=ContractorsNoVPN,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,o=StaffLDAP"/>
        <group name="ContractorsVPN" access-id="CN=ContractorsVPN,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,o=StaffLDAP"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="MANAGER">
        <group name="AssistantManagers" access-id="CN=AssistantManagers,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,o=ManagersLDAP"/>
        <group name="Managers" access-id="CN=Managers,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,OU=Some Unit,o=ManagersLDAP"/>
        <group name="TestManagers"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="ADMIN">
        <group name="Admin" access-id="group:someRealm/CN=Team,OU=Groups,OU=Divison,OU=Region,o=AdminsLDAP"/>
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```